# Confused about result of BigDecimal

Tags: java, bigdecimal

How come `BigDecimal(9105.0).div(BigDecimal(100.toDouble()))`=91.0 instead of 91.05.  How do I retain the precision in the decimal?

Comment: `System.out.println(new BigDecimal(9105).divide(new BigDecimal(100)).toString());` prints `91.05` for me. What code are you using?

Comment: edited the code, try that.  91.0 instead of 91.05

Comment: that snippet isn't valid Java code. can you explain (and remove the label?)

Comment: That is not Java code, e.g. `100.toDouble()` is certainly not valid Java. Please specify language you're actually using, or specify real Java code you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use the .div method instead of the .divide method

the kotlin implementation for .div is:

```
@kotlin.internal.InlineOnly
public inline operator fun BigDecimal.div(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal = this.divide(other, RoundingMode.HALF_EVEN)
```

as you can see, there is automatically a RoundingMode activated